# Display whole image in circulr shape using Javascript or HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

How can I display whole image in circulr shape using Javascript or HTML5. I tried the code below but with this code only part of the image will be converted into circular shape. How can I make the whole display in circular shape?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
      #myCanvas {
        border: 1px solid #9C9898;
      }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" >

</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
    <div id="myCanvas"></div>
    <script>
     var ctx = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext("2d");
      ctx.arc(100,100, 50, 0, Math.PI*2,true); // you can use any shape
      ctx.clip();

        var img = new Image();
        img.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, 200, 300);
 }, true);
img.src="images/hospital_review_profile_placeholder.png";


    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ctx.clip(), you would resize and reposition your image to fit in your circle.

Here is code that will resize your image to its largest size that will fit in the circle.

Then the code positions the resized image properly in the circle.

Here is a Fiddle ---  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/s6MzZ/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
    $(function(){

        var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

        var radius=50;      // circle radius
        var fullWidth=200;  // actual width of image in pixels
        var fullHeight=300; // actual height of image in pixels
        var centerX=100;    // center X coordinate of the circle
        var centerY=100;    // center Y coordinate of the Circle

        // the image must be resized to fit into the circle
        // Call CalcResizedImageDimensions() to get the resized width/height
        var size=CalcResizedImageDimensions(radius,fullWidth,fullHeight);

        var rectX=centerX-size.width/2; // the X coordinate of the resized rectangle
        var rectY=centerY-size.height/2 // the Y coordinate of the resized rectangle

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(centerX,centerY,radius,0,Math.PI*2,true);

        // I illustrate with just a rectangle
        // you would drawImage() instead
        ctx.rect(rectX,rectY,size.width,size.height);
        ctx.stroke();

        function CalcResizedImageDimensions(r,w,h){
            var d=2*r;
            var newH=(d*h)/Math.sqrt(w*w+h*h);
            var newW=w/h*newH;
            return({width:newW,height:newH});
        }

    }); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>

<canvas id="canvas" width=200 height=200></canvas>


</body>
</html>
```